# boostrap carousel not working/images are just being displayed on atop the other

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So,i'm new to this ,the bootstrap carousel isn't working for me,I took the example straight from w3school and it's still not working it only displays the images one atop of the other,admittedly this is a rushed job ,so I may have missed something blindingly obvious.Not to mention my coding knowledge is really patchy,my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pagrindinis puslapis</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>//logotipas
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Pagrindinis</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Visos prekės</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Populiariausios prekės</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nuolaidos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pristatymas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontaktai</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Prisijungimas/Užsisakymas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="bob.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="young.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="thing.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Footer Text</p>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the carousel-item class. Replace it with with item class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace carousel-item with item for bootstrap 3 carousels.

Here's the code

```
<!-- The slideshow -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1100x500" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1100x500" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1100x500" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's done it! Thanks I appreciate it,though I don't get it ,I'm pretty sure I was using bootstrap 4,hmm

Comment: @Auridas You can see in the stylesheet URL that it is version 3. You can get version 4 from the official docs, but there are breaking changes between the versions.

Comment: @Auridas in your code, you are using bootstrap version 3 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7'